# Removing www from WP site URL from settings panel

Tags: wordpress, url

I have a Wordpress site
my website URL is http://www.domainname.com

In wp settings panel there are two fields showing 
Wordpress Address : http://www.domainname.com
Site Address : http://www.domainname.com

I want my website URL to be http://domainname.com

My question is if i just change "Site Address" and remove www from it, will it cause any harm to my site ?
I dont have domain name with http://domainname.com
I only have  http://www.domainname.com
Will the change work smoothly ?
I want that when my site accessed it shows http://domainname.com in URL bar of browser.
and when some post or page is clicked it will show http://domainname.com/postname.

Comment: Why would you want your site like that anyway? It will be slower in some instances..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .htaccess file to something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you have any Wordpress permalinks, you'll want to copy that over too.  Here's an example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Enter in new lines of code here
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: will it require any server restart ?

Comment: Can i access .htaccess file from dashboard like theme php files ?

Comment: Permalinks usually deals with that kind of thing, but I don't think you can actually edit it so I would suggest using FTP to edit it, it will be in the public directory of the website (usually public_html).

Comment: If i remove www from Site sddress feild in settings panel of wp-admin, will that not work ?

Comment: can you plaese explain these lines of code                                %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: Not yet. I am afraid that if it fails my site will collapse and will redirect to some other site actually named http://domain.com.

Comment: If anyone accesses any folder/page on your website, say domain.com/page, it will automatically change the beginning of the address to http://domain.com/page - same goes with http://www.domain.com - it will change to http://domain.com

Comment: Of course you will need to change `domain.com` to your actual domain name!

Comment: Collapse and be sucked into a black hole? I don't think so - as long as you change the domain name, you'll be fine.  It also might be worth mentioning that if you have any permalinks set up, copy them over too.  See my updated answer.

Comment: And I meant have you tried changing it in your Wordpress settings as you explained?

Comment: Yes you are rite. obviously domain.com is just example name i will change my actual url say if i have "http://www.technologyinside.com" i will change it to "http://technologyinside.com"

Comment: I need advise of a pro about it weather i should change it from admin panel or not

Comment: It depends on your permissions of that file, generally it won't be editable through Wordpress. If you tell me what your .htaccess file says, I'll happily add it in there for you.

Comment: Yeah, like I said before, go for it - nothing can really go wrong, you just change it back at worst.